# Expression inside angular-timer module on Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

I have installed the [angular-timer](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/) module on my application.

It works fine when I use it like the examples on that page, for instance, the code below yields the correct output:

```
<timer start-time="1357020000000">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>
```

However, when I insert an expression inside the start-time attribute, I get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24parse/syntax?p0=order.lastUpdatedDate&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B%3a%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Border.lastUpdatedDate%7D%7D&p4=order.lastUpdatedDate%7D%7D)

The expression {{order.lastUpdatedDate}} if used outside an attribute, correctly outputs the time in miliseconds, and if I copy-paste that result into an start-time attribute on the directive, it works!

So my guess is that this directive doesn't work with expressions... :(

I want to correct that, but I'm fairly new to Angular and I don't know how to begin.

Can anybody help me, or at least point a direction for me to research, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the {{ }}

```
<timer start-time="order.lastUpdateDate">
```

Comment: Wow... that was it! I'm feeling dumb right now haha . I think I might study how directives work so I don't make the same mistake again. thank you! haha

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Any attributes related to a directive should evaluate an expression and therefore don't need the template tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gotcha: the start-time attribute is evaluated only once during start.
In your example,  order.lastUpdateDate might actually be calculated *after* the timer starts because it autostarts, so the timer will not show what you would expect.

There are a few ways to fix this:

1. stop and start the timer after the value changed,
2. Change the code to evaluate the start-time in the tick function (simplest approach,works for me)
3. Change the code to set up a watch to detect when the start-time value changes and reevaluate it.